# write wrapper for matlabs save function

Tags: matlab

I would to write a wrapper for the `save` function of matlab with predefined options (predefined `version` in my case to allow saving large files), i.e. something like this

```
save('parameters.mat', 'some', 'parameters', 'here', '-v.3');
```

should turn into this

```
save_large('parameters.mat', 'some', 'parameters', 'here');
```

where `save_large` is a wrapper for `save` with `version` set to `'-v7.3'`:

```
function [  ] = save_large( filename, varargin )
%varargin to allow for multiple variable storing?

%what to write here to save all variables (declared as chars) stored in
%the workspace where 'save_large' was called with version set to '-v7.3'?

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the variables won't exist in the scope of the function `save_large`, you will have to use `evalin` to get the variable from the `"caller"` workspace.

Using `try` we can also ensure that the variable *exists* in the caller workspace.

To get the correct variable names within your `.mat` file, we could either use the (discouraged) `eval` function, or the below method which assigns all of the variables to a struct, and then use the `-struct` flag in `save`.

```
function save_large(filename, varargin)
    % Set up struct for saving
    savestruct = struct();
    for n = 1:numel(varargin)
        % Test if variable exists in caller workspace
        % Do this by trying to assign to struct
        % Use parentheses for creating field equal to string from varargin 
        try savestruct.(varargin{n}) = evalin('caller', varargin{n});
            % Successful assignment to struct, no action needed
        catch
            warning(['Could not find variable: ', varargin{n}]);
        end
    end
    save(filename, '-struct', 'savestruct', '-v7.3');
end
```

---

Example

```
% Create dummy variables and save them
a = magic(3);
b = 'abc';
save_large test.mat a b; 
% Clear workspace to get rid of a and b
clear a b
exist a var % false
exist b var % false
% Load from file
load test.mat
% a and b in workspace
exist a var % true
exist b var % true
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting, I realised you could remove `v` entirely, updated code is presumably more memory efficient as no intermediate variable needed.